# Values of x for the the geometric series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem is,

$4^n (x+2)^n$ with $n$ going to $0$.

After applying the ratio test I'm getting the absolute value of $4(x+2)$. If the $4$ wasn't there I'm pretty sure the interval would be $(-2,2)$, but with the $4$ there I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^n(x+2)^n$?

Comment: No, n = 0 is correct.

Comment: this is a terrible name for a variable whose limit is 0...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** the series
$$
\sum z^n
$$converges only when $|z|<1$.